# Redirect user to specific section/div of page after login/registration

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose a user is looking into some section of page and he is not logged in. He than logs in through the link given in the page. How can I redirect the user to specific section that he was reading.

Note: I have already redirected the user to initial page but still can't redirect to the specific section.

Comment: Dit you tried to add a # symbol with the Id of the section when using redirect?

Comment: I was also having a similar issue

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`intended()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication) method:

```
return redirect()->intended();
```

This method reads the `url.intended` value from the session and if it exists, the method redirects a user to this URL. If not, by default it redirects a user to `/`

To make it work with a section, use JS to get full URL:

```
window.location.href
```

Then you could make an AJAX call to save current URL to the session manually with:

`session(['url.intended' => url()->full()])`

Or you could put it into a hidden input and then in a `LoginController` get it from a request and save it to the session.

Comment: the intended method only redirects the user to initial page.

Comment: This method reads the `url.intended` value from the session and if it exists, it redirects a user to this URL. If not, by default it redirects a user to `/`.

Comment: but i need to redirect the user to specific div section of page. Is it possible?

Comment: @Yojan you mean `http://example.com/page#section`? In this case, you need to use JS to get after `#` part and save full URL manually. There is no way to do that with just PHP.

Comment: Could a you pass an URL parameter with the login link from the section and then use that parameter as an anchor link?

Answer (score 0):

The way i did it:

In `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php` i update the handle function like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect('login')->with(['lastUrl' => $request->url()]);
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

The important part is `return redirect('login')->with(['lastUrl' => $request->url()]);`. That way i got the intended url the user tried to access before login so when i login i just redirect the user to the url he tried to access.

In case the user didn't try to access any page he is just redirected to the default welcome page.